# How to integrate jsplumb in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, jsplumb

I have tried jsplumb script in .html file under the script tag. This is working fine.

```
 <body>
    <div id="q-app"></div> 
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script>
   jsPlumb.ready(function() {
            jsPlumb.connect({
                source:"item_left",
                target:"item_right",
                endpoint:"Rectangle"
            });
            jsPlumb.draggable("item_left");
            jsPlumb.draggable("item_right");
        });
  </script>
  </body>
```

But now i want to integrate this jsplumb code/script in .vue file.I tried to put this script in .vue file under script tag, but i did not get any output except an blank page with zero errors. How can i proceed further?.Guide me with some simple example.

Comment: I guess you need to import jsplumb in your script. Try that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

**mydraggableview.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div id="diagramContainer">
        <div id="item_left" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item_right" class="item" style="margin-left:50px;"></div>
      </div>
    </template> 

    <script>
    import jsplumb from 'jsplumb'
    export default {
     props: ['yourProps'],
     data() {
      return {
        your: data
      }
    },
    mounted(){
          jsPlumb.ready(function() {
                jsPlumb.connect({
                    source:"item_left",
                    target:"item_right",
                    endpoint:"Rectangle"
                })
            })
          }
        }
    </script>
```

Then you can import where you are going to use it.

**otherfile.js**

```
<script>
    import myDraggableComponent from './path/to/component/mydraggableview'
</script>
```

and use it as directive or inside your component.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to put together working code based on jsplumb demo community [example](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/flowchart/index.html)  -

```
<template>
     <div id="canvas" class="jtk-demo-canvas canvas-wide flowchart-demo jtk-surface jtk-surface-nopan">
        <div id="flowchartWindow1" class="window jtk-node">1</div>        
        <div id="flowchartWindow2" class="window jtk-node">2</div>
        <div id="flowchartWindow3" class="window jtk-node">3</div>
        <div id="flowchartWindow4" class="window jtk-node">4</div>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
import { jsPlumb as JSPlumb } from 'jsplumb'
export default {
  name: 'JsPlumb',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    JSPlumb.ready(function() {
        var instance = window.jsp = JSPlumb.getInstance({
            // default drag options
            DragOptions: { cursor: 'pointer', zIndex: 2000 },
            // the overlays to decorate each connection with.  note that the label overlay uses a function to generate the label text; in this
            // case it returns the 'labelText' member that we set on each connection in the 'init' method below.
            ConnectionOverlays: [
                [ "Arrow", {
                    location: 1,
                    visible:true,
                    width:11,
                    length:11,
                    id:"ARROW",
                    events:{
                        click:function() { alert("you clicked on the arrow overlay")}
                    }
                } ],
                [ "Label", {
                    location: 0.1,
                    id: "label",
                    cssClass: "aLabel",
                    events:{
                        tap:function() { alert("hey"); }
                    }
                }]
            ],
            Container: "canvas"
        });
        var basicType = {
            connector: "StateMachine",
            paintStyle: { stroke: "red", strokeWidth: 4 },
            hoverPaintStyle: { stroke: "blue" },
            overlays: [
                "Arrow"
            ]
        };
        instance.registerConnectionType("basic", basicType);
        // this is the paint style for the connecting lines..
        var connectorPaintStyle = {
                strokeWidth: 2,
                stroke: "#61B7CF",
                joinstyle: "round",
                outlineStroke: "white",
                outlineWidth: 2
            },
        // .. and this is the hover style.
            connectorHoverStyle = {
                strokeWidth: 3,
                stroke: "#216477",
                outlineWidth: 5,
                outlineStroke: "white"
            },
            endpointHoverStyle = {
                fill: "#216477",
                stroke: "#216477"
            },
        // the definition of source endpoints (the small blue ones)
            sourceEndpoint = {
                endpoint: "Dot",
                paintStyle: {
                    stroke: "#7AB02C",
                    fill: "transparent",
                    radius: 7,
                    strokeWidth: 1
                },
                isSource: true,
                connector: [ "Flowchart", { stub: [40, 60], gap: 10, cornerRadius: 5, alwaysRespectStubs: true } ],
                connectorStyle: connectorPaintStyle,
                hoverPaintStyle: endpointHoverStyle,
                connectorHoverStyle: connectorHoverStyle,
                dragOptions: {},
                overlays: [
                    [ "Label", {
                        location: [0.5, 1.5],
                        label: "Drag",
                        cssClass: "endpointSourceLabel",
                        visible:false
                    } ]
                ]
            },
        // the definition of target endpoints (will appear when the user drags a connection)
            targetEndpoint = {
                endpoint: "Dot",
                paintStyle: { fill: "#7AB02C", radius: 7 },
                hoverPaintStyle: endpointHoverStyle,
                maxConnections: -1,
                dropOptions: { hoverClass: "hover", activeClass: "active" },
                isTarget: true,
                overlays: [
                    [ "Label", { location: [0.5, -0.5], label: "Drop", cssClass: "endpointTargetLabel", visible:false } ]
                ]
            },
            init = function (connection) {
                connection.getOverlay("label").setLabel(connection.sourceId.substring(15) + "-" + connection.targetId.substring(15));
            };

        var _addEndpoints = function (toId, sourceAnchors, targetAnchors) {
            for (var i = 0; i < sourceAnchors.length; i++) {
                var sourceUUID = toId + sourceAnchors[i];
                instance.addEndpoint("flowchart" + toId, sourceEndpoint, {
                    anchor: sourceAnchors[i], uuid: sourceUUID
                });
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < targetAnchors.length; j++) {
                var targetUUID = toId + targetAnchors[j];
                instance.addEndpoint("flowchart" + toId, targetEndpoint, { anchor: targetAnchors[j], uuid: targetUUID });
            }
        };

        // suspend drawing and initialise.
        instance.batch(function () {

            _addEndpoints("Window4", ["TopCenter", "BottomCenter"], ["LeftMiddle", "RightMiddle"]);
            _addEndpoints("Window2", ["LeftMiddle", "BottomCenter"], ["TopCenter", "RightMiddle"]);
            _addEndpoints("Window3", ["RightMiddle", "BottomCenter"], ["LeftMiddle", "TopCenter"]);
            _addEndpoints("Window1", ["LeftMiddle", "RightMiddle"], ["TopCenter", "BottomCenter"]);

            // listen for new connections; initialise them the same way we initialise the connections at startup.
            instance.bind("connection", function (connInfo, originalEvent) {
                init(connInfo.connection);
            });

            // make all the window divs draggable
            instance.draggable(JSPlumb.getSelector(".flowchart-demo .window"), { grid: [20, 20] });
            // THIS DEMO ONLY USES getSelector FOR CONVENIENCE. Use your library's appropriate selector
            // method, or document.querySelectorAll:
            //JSPlumb.draggable(document.querySelectorAll(".window"), { grid: [20, 20] });

            // connect a few up
            instance.connect({uuids: ["Window2BottomCenter", "Window3TopCenter"]});
            instance.connect({uuids: ["Window2LeftMiddle", "Window4LeftMiddle"]});
            instance.connect({uuids: ["Window4TopCenter", "Window4RightMiddle"]});
            instance.connect({uuids: ["Window3RightMiddle", "Window2RightMiddle"]});
            instance.connect({uuids: ["Window4BottomCenter", "Window1TopCenter"]});
            instance.connect({uuids: ["Window3BottomCenter", "Window1BottomCenter"] });
            //

            //
            // listen for clicks on connections, and offer to delete connections on click.
            //
            instance.bind("click", function (conn, originalEvent) {
            // if (confirm("Delete connection from " + conn.sourceId + " to " + conn.targetId + "?"))
                //   instance.detach(conn);
                conn.toggleType("basic");
            });

            instance.bind("connectionDrag", function (connection) {
                console.log("connection " + connection.id + " is being dragged. suspendedElement is ", connection.suspendedElement, " of type ", connection.suspendedElementType);
            });

            instance.bind("connectionDragStop", function (connection) {
                console.log("connection " + connection.id + " was dragged");
            });

            instance.bind("connectionMoved", function (params) {
                console.log("connection " + params.connection.id + " was moved");
            });
        });

        JSPlumb.fire("jsPlumbDemoLoaded", instance);        
    })
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.item{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
.demo {
    /* for IE10+ touch devices */
    touch-action:none;
}

.flowchart-demo .window {
    border: 1px solid #346789;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #eeeeef;
    color: black;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
    -o-transition: -o-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
    transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
}

.flowchart-demo .window:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #444;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #444;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #444;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.flowchart-demo .active {
    border: 1px dotted green;
}

.flowchart-demo .hover {
    border: 1px dotted red;
}

#flowchartWindow1 {
    top: 34em;
    left: 5em;
}

#flowchartWindow2 {
    top: 7em;
    left: 36em;
}

#flowchartWindow3 {
    top: 27em;
    left: 48em;
}

#flowchartWindow4 {
    top: 23em;
    left: 22em;
}

.flowchart-demo .jtk-connector {
    z-index: 4;
}

.flowchart-demo .jtk-endpoint, .endpointTargetLabel, .endpointSourceLabel {
    z-index: 21;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.flowchart-demo .aLabel {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.4em;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    z-index: 21;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.flowchart-demo .aLabel.jtk-hover {
    background-color: #5C96BC;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.window.jtk-connected {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.jtk-drag {
    outline: 4px solid pink !important;
}

path, .jtk-endpoint {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.jtk-overlay {
    background-color:transparent;
}
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* --- page structure --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #434343;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.jtk-bootstrap {
  min-height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}

.jtk-bootstrap .jtk-page-container {
    display:flex;
    width:100vw;
    justify-content: center;
    flex:1;
  }

  .jtk-bootstrap .jtk-container {
    width: 60%;
    max-width:800px;
  }

  .jtk-bootstrap-wide .jtk-container {
      width: 80%;
      max-width:1187px;
  }

.jtk-demo-main {    
    position: relative;
    margin-top:98px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.jtk-demo-main .description {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    background-color: #f4f5ef;
}

.jtk-demo-main .description li {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
}

.jtk-demo-canvas {    
    height:750px;
    max-height:700px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background-color:white;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow:1;
}

.canvas-wide {
    margin-left:0;
}

.miniview {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    z-index: 100;
}


.jtk-demo-dataset {
    text-align: left;
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.demo-title {
    float:left;
    font-size:18px;
}

.controls {
    top: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    display:flex;
}

.controls i {
    background-color: #5184a0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* ------------------------ node palette -------------------- */

.sidebar {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 0;
    background-color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    align-items: center;
}

.sidebar-item {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border-radius: 11px;
    color: #585858;
    cursor: move;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 128px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    outline:none;
}

button.sidebar-item {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:150px;
}

.sidebar select {
    height:35px;
    width:150px;
    outline:none;
}

.sidebar-item.katavorio-clone-drag {
    margin:0;
    border:1px solid white;
}

.sidebar-item:hover, .sidebar-item.katavorio-clone-drag {
    background-color: #5184a0;
    color:white;
}

/*
.sidebar button {
    background-color: #30686d;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding: 7px;
    color: white;
    cursor:pointer;
}*/

.sidebar i {
    float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .sidebar {
        float:none;
        height: 55px;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top:0;
    }

    .sidebar ul li {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-top: 7px;
        width:67px;
    }
    .jtk-demo-canvas {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top:10px;
        height:364px;
    }
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* --- jsPlumb setup ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.jtk-surface-pan {
    display:none;
}

.jtk-connector {
    z-index:9;
}

.jtk-connector:hover, .jtk-connector.jtk-hover {
    z-index:10;
}

.jtk-endpoint {
    z-index:12;
    opacity:0.8;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.jtk-overlay {
    background-color: white;
    color: #434343;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 4px;
    z-index:10;

}

.jtk-overlay.jtk-hover {
    color: #434343;
}

path {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.delete {
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.add, .edit {
    cursor: pointer;
    float:right;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-right:2px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.edit:hover {
    color: #ff8000;
}

.selected-mode {
    color:#E4F013;
}

.connect {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#f76258;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 13px;
    right: 5px;
}

/* header styles */

.demo-links {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 57px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index:100001;
}

.demo-links div {
    display:inline;
    margin-right:7px;
    margin-left:7px;
}

.demo-links i {
    padding:4px;
}

.jtk-node {
    background-color: #5184a0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width:80px;
    min-height:30px;
    width: auto;
}

.jtk-node .name {

    color: white;
    cursor: move;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: center;
}

.jtk-node .name span {
    cursor:pointer;

}

[undo], [redo] { background-color:darkgray !important; }
[can-undo='true'] [undo], [can-redo='true'] [redo] { background-color: #3E7E9C  !important; }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the official article to integrate with VueJs:

https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/toolkit/current/articles/demo-vue2.html

Comment: That is the toolkit version of jsPlumb. From the given code snippet above, it only uses the community version.